# smartphones and buttons

Tags: compact-framework, button, touchscreen, smartphone

The .net compact framework on smartphones doesn't know the button component, the reasons are unknown to me. My question is: how do people usually get over this problem? I have know smartphone near me to check out, only a pda phone, which of course has touch screen and supports the button component.

What would you do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of buttons is intentional as it violates Microsoft guidelines for smartphone platform. Instead you should use the menu, which for a thumb operated device is faster. It also helps to provide a common interface for all phone's applications.

If you need to have a button, you can easily create one of your own. see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286286/windows-mobile-5-sdk-button-control#286408).