# NotSupportedException when creating button with .NET CF on CE5 device?

Tags: .net, winforms, compact-framework

I have an application that runs well on WinCE and WM devices (all that I have tested so far).
I have just received a new device to test on and the Form throws a NotSupportedException when the designer creates a button on the device.

The device is a Motorola EWP2100 Wifi Phone.
According to its about page it runs WinCE 5

Here is the full exception it throws

> System.NotSupportedException occurred
>     Message="NotSupportedException"
>     StackTrace:
>       at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InitInstance()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase..ctor()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Button..ctor()
>       at SmartLane.Config.InitializeComponent()
>       at SmartLane.Config..ctor()
>       at SmartLane.MainForm.ShowConfig()
>       at SmartLane.MainForm.MainForm_Load()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Form._SetVisibleNotify()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
>       at SmartLane.Program.Main()
>     InnerException:

The code that throws it is here:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.txtServerAddress = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.btnOK = new System.Windows.Forms.Button(); //<---- THIS THROWS
        ...
    }
```

I know its quite a specific thing to ask, but I have never run into this problem before and the Exception doesn't really give me a clue as to what's going wrong here.

I appreciate any advice or suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using Smartphone (Standard) SDK, which doesn't support Buttons.

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286286/windows-mobile-5-sdk-button-control).

Comment: Rofl. After reading the link I never even considered how a user might even press the button on the screen.  Thanks!

Comment: They'd use the button the same way people who don't use a mouse on a PC use them:  TAB the focus to the button and then hit ENTER (or whatever it's labeled on the phone).  I understand why they took it out, but they should have left it in.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: one of the many places where the CF team apparently couldn't see the forest for all the trees.

Comment: Not using buttons make the applications consistent with the built-in UI. For users that only owned Windows Mobile devices that makes sense. People who have used other phones find this strange. I had to implement my own Button once, because the client asked for the exact port of a J2ME application to Windows Mobile. I guess this is happening all the time.